# Custom ordering in Max()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, max

Suppose I have a table 'things' which has a column 'ranking'. There are 5 records with the values First, Second, Third, Fourth and Fifth in the ranking column.

I want to be able to use

```
select Max(ranking) from things
```

to return 'Fifth', instead of its default 'Third'.

Also, I would want Fourth to be considered greater than Third, etc. etc.

How can I accomplish this?

SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `max(ranking)`, I would suggest:

```
select top 1 ranking
from things
order by ranking desc;
```

That doesn't solve your problem, but it points to a good direction.  Just use a `case` statement in the `order by`:

```
select top 1 ranking
from things
order by (case ranking
              when 'First' then 1
              when 'Second' then 2
              when 'Third' then 3
              when 'Fourth' then 4
              when 'Fifth' then 5
          end) desc;
```

You can also do this lookup using an auxiliary table or subquery.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have a separate lookup table to link those values to a numeric value which can be ordered by.